# What is the etymology of the saying "tables are meant for glasses not arses"?

Tags: etymology

What is the etymology of the saying:

> Tables are meant for glasses not arses

It is a saying my gran used to use and I have not heard it recently.

Comment: I think you mean *asses*; otherwise it doesn't rhyme.

Comment: You mean, where does it come from? "Etymology" denotes the origin of a word.

Comment: It comes from sticking your arse on the table.

Comment: @tchrist in (many) British accents it would rhyme

Comment: @tchrist - It rhymes when I say it...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the meaning behind it is something like "tables are meant to be looked at, not meant to be sat on"

Comment: Surely it's *drinking* glasses

Comment: Please add a source to support your answer.

Comment: Also,  the question doesn’t ask for the meaning.